# How to specify optional string parameters in a function signature and identify the pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

As a newbie, I've got a rather simple question.

I would like to define a function that accepts one of a few possible strings.

I.e., I wish to do the following.

```
f[s_"a"|"b"] := do something useful with s
```

But of course that syntax doesn't work. Note that the function definition is not overloaded.

I achieved this the following way.

```
f[key2_ /; MemberQ[Map[StringMatchQ[key2, #] &, {"Cat", "Bird", "Mouse"}], True]] := someAssoc["Key1"][key2]
```

Is there a better way to express this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html):

```
f[s : "a" | "b"] := s <> ": stuff"
f /@ {"a", "b", "c", 2}
```

> {"a: stuff", "b: stuff", f["c"], f[2]}

Comment: Great thanks. As I suspected, the language has an affordance.

Comment: @CalvinDale, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.